# How can I stop Ruby if/elsif statement from looping?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, methods, syntax, syntax-error

I am teaching myself Ruby by making a small game in order to test out how I feel about the language. My code was going rather smoothly until I encountered a problem in which the first decision of the game loops instead of progressing forwards.

This code is what I have been using for a short part in the Exposition of my game.

```
    def getup_or_sleep?
        puts"Cole";
        puts"----";
        puts"Will you get up or go back to sleep?";
        decision = gets
        if decision == "sleep";
            puts"Cole";
            puts"----";
            puts"You decide to go back sleep. It is far too early.";
        elsif decision == "get up";
            Exposition.stretch
        else;
            Exposition.getup_or_sleep?
    end
```

This is the expected result I was hoping to achieve:

### Cole

Will you get up or go back to sleep?
*If player chooses 'sleep'*

### 1)Cole

You decide to go back to sleep, it is far too early.
*I plan to make a new method to direct the user to, but I first want to fix this issue.

**if player chooses 'get up'
->>> to stretch method which is inside of the same class.

I'm new to coding so I may be confused on a few things. Thanks in advance! =)

Comment: With your approach, every method will call another method but never actually return. In the run of the game, you'll build a massive stack of method calls that way. It might be better to have each method _return_ the new player state, e.g. `:sleeping` or `:stretching`. You could then decide what to do with the current state in your main game loop.

Answer (score 2):

Your method calls itself recursively because it all conditions fail, and it always falls back to the `else` branch.

This happens because `gets` reads input from the user and returns the input *including* the invisible newline character that is added when the user hits the enter key. But your conditions do not include such new line characters.

A common Ruby idiom is to call `gets.chomp` to get user input, where the [`chomp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#method-i-chomp) removes the newline character from the input.

Just change this line `decision = gets` to

```
decision = gets.chomp
```

to fix your issue.

Apart from that, your code isn't following Ruby idioms, for example, Ruby does not require a `;` at the end of a line, or you usually add a whitespace between a method name and its argument, like in `puts "Cole"`. Therefore, I suggest formatting your code like this:

```
def getup_or_sleep?
  puts 'Cole'
  puts '----'
  puts 'Will you get up or go back to sleep?'
  
  decision = gets.chomp
    
  if decision == 'sleep'
    puts 'Cole'
    puts '----'
    puts 'You decide to go back sleep. It is far too early.'
  elsif decision == 'get up'
    Exposition.stretch
  else
    Exposition.getup_or_sleep?
  end
end
```

Or with a `case` block and some duplication extracted into a method:

```
def greeting
  puts 'Cole'
  puts '----'
end

def getup_or_sleep?
  greeting
  puts 'Will you get up or go back to sleep?'
  
  case gets.chomp
  when 'sleep'
    greeting
    puts 'You decide to go back sleep. It is far too early.'
  when 'get up'
    Exposition.stretch
  else
    Exposition.getup_or_sleep?
  end
end
```

Comment: Possibly also `case decision.downcase ... end`

Comment: Good idea, but I didn't want to introduce too many new concepts in my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I just used the ; because someone told me to lol.

Comment: I have done some research and I understand the usage of 'case' as well! Thanks a ton.